# Using two network connection types on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

My home network has a single router/fibre adaptor that provides internet to the house. Several devices are hardwired (3) to it and many more (3-10) connect via WiFi. My PC upstairs uses a powerline adaptor to get a 4th hardwired connection. I notice on occasion this was dropping recently at inconvenient times.

I had a spare WiFi dongle so I plugged it, connected it to the WiFi network and then Bridged the two adaptors in the control panel.

My question is, what did I just do?

What I would like to achieve is for the WiFi adaptor to be used when the powerline adaptor connection drops connectivity. Is this what I have in place, if not is it something I can configure?

Comment: You should break the bridge otherwise you have what is know as a loop and this can bring down your network https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switching_loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your computer will default to one connection and fall back on another.  It should default to using Ethernet and fall back on the WiFi dongle.

I actually had a similar situation using WiFi for internet and an Ethernet connection to a server I was running (to avoid a slower PC to Router to Server connection).  When connecting to my server, the Ethernet connection was defaulted to and if I disconnected it, WiFi was used.

You can test this by, perhaps, streaming a video and disconnecting your Ethernet during the stream.